# how efficiently use overload and polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading

I have a `BaseObj`:

```
public abstract class BaseObj {
    String name;
    public BaseObj(String _name) {
        name = _name;
    }

    public void report(){
        System.out.println(name + " is " + getType());
    }

    public abstract String getType();

}
```

and two subclasses `Sample1` and `Sample2`:

```
public class Sample1 extends BaseObj{
    private float var;
    public Sample1(String name,float _var){
        super(name);
        var = _var;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "Float: " + Float.toString(var);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Sample2 extends BaseObj{
    private int var;
    public Sample2(String name , int _var){
        super(name);
        var = _var;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "Integer: " + Integer.toString(var);
    }

}
```

in the main calss:

```
public class Poly {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        BaseObj mObj[] = new BaseObj[4];

        // Hard-definition of the object tyte
        mObj[0] = new Sample1("X1",(float)12.34);
        mObj[1] = new Sample2("X2",12);
        mObj[2] = new Sample2("X3",12);
        mObj[3] = new Sample1("X4",(float)1.2);

        for(BaseObj x:mObj){
            x.report();
        }
    }
}
```

I have to Hard-define the type of mObj elements. But I'm searching for a way using `overload` to avoid this kind of hard deffinition, e.g. in a new class i use overload to get right object based on its inputs:

```
public class Sample{
    public Sample(String _name , int _var){
        // get Sample2 object
    }
    public Sample(String _name , float _var){
        // get Sample1 object
    }
}
```

then I would be able to change the code of my main calss as follows:

```
public class Poly {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        BaseObj mObj[] = new BaseObj[4];

        mObj[0] = new Sample("X1",(float)12.34);
        mObj[1] = new Sample("X2",12);
        mObj[2] = new Sample("X3",12);
        mObj[3] = new Sample("X4",(float)1.2);

        for(BaseObj x:mObj){
            x.report();
        }
    }
}
```

the output is currently as follows:

```
X1 is Float: 12.34
X2 is Integer: 12
X3 is Integer: 12
X4 is Float: 1.2
```

Edit: what exactly I need is to define elements of mObj as `new Sample("X1",var)` and not some of them as `new Sample1("X1",(float)12.34)` and some as `new Sample2("X1",12)`. For this I shoud decide about of the type of my object in the constructors of the class `Sample`. 
whould anybody have any idea?
Thanks

Comment: What did you expect to happen?  You have overloaded your constructor and it appears to be doing what you asked for already.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I think they are asking if there is a way to avoid the `new Sample(....)` code in their main class. They are trying to see if they can have the compiler implicitly know what type each element in `mObj` is.

I think

Comment: @Marcin There is no way to avoid using a constructor or a static factory method to create the object.  Java doesn't support creating objects via casting (except with auto boxing)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yup. I understand that. I think that is what the author is asking for, however. (No constructor)

Comment: @Peter: it is a simplified version of my code. In the original one my mObj array is relatively long and I had to use lots of if-else statements. And I am trying to find a more efficint way to do this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a factory method here.

```
public class BaseObjFactory {
   public static BaseObj create(String name, int value) {
      return new Sample2(name, value);
   }

   public static BaseObj create(String name, float value) {
      return new Sample1(name, value);
   }
}
```

and use it this way

```
mObj[0] = BaseObjFactory.create("X1",12.34f);
mObj[1] = BaseObjFactory.create("X2",12);
mObj[2] = BaseObjFactory.create("X3",12);
mObj[3] = BaseObjFactory.create("X4",1.2f);
```

Btw. no need to use a cast `(float)1.2`, just append an `f` to make it a `float` literal.

Comment: It seams it is what I need, thanks! but could you please explain the first part of your code?

Comment: It's the definition of the Factory, I use two overloaded methods `create` for instantiating the instances, so the compiler will choose the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Use factory methods.

```
class SampleFactory {
    Sample1 create(String name, int value) {
        return new Sample1(name, value);
    }

    Sample2 create(String name, float value) {
        return new Sample2(name, value);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as

```
mObj[0] = SampleFactory.create("X1",(float)12.34);
mObj[1] = SampleFactory.create("X2",12);
mObj[2] = SampleFactory.create("X3",12);
mObj[3] = SampleFactory.create("X4",(float)1.2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start with the simplest solution for what you are trying to achieve.

```
public class Poly {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample[] mObj = {
                new Sample("X1", 12.34f),
                new Sample("X2", 12),
                new Sample("X3", 12),
                new Sample("X4", 1.2f)
        };

        for (Sample x : mObj) 
            x.report();
    }
}

class Sample {
    private final String desc;
    private final Number value;

    public Sample(String desc, Number value) {
        this.desc = desc;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void report() {
        System.out.println(desc + " is a " + value.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + value);
    }
}
```

prints

```
X1 is a Float: 12.34
X2 is a Integer: 12
X3 is a Integer: 12
X4 is a Float: 1.2
```

This uses polymorphism in that Float and Integer are subclasses of Number.

Comment: off course my code is not the easiest solution but  I just simplified my code to explain the problem. In my original  I have sth else instead of getType()